# Can you pass an initializer rather than a function/closure when using Swift's map?

Tags: swift

Consider a `Dictionary` of motorcycle names and descriptions:

```
let data = ["Betty" : "Very fast", "Mike" : "Easy going"]
```

And a simple `Motorcycle` class with two properties.

```
class Motorcycle {

    let name: String
    let description: String

    init(name: String, description: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
    }

}
```

Aaand a contrived function that accepts two `String` values and returns a `Motorcycle`.

```
func genMotorcycle(name: String, desc: String) -> Motorcycle {
    return Motorcycle(name: name, description: desc)
}
```

Now, assuming you wanted to transform the `Dictionary` to a `[Motorcycle]`, you could:

```
let motorcycles = map(data) { Motorcycle(name: $0, description: $1) }
```

Or, using the contrived `genMotorcycle` function:

```
let motorcycles = map(data, genMotorcycle)
```

Since `genMotorcycle` *feels* like it has the same type (`(String, String) -> Motorcycle`) as the `Motorcycle` initializer, I was wondering if there is some way I might refer to the `Motorcycle` initializer rather than, say, `genMotorcycle`.

In other words, is there a way to validly express the following?

```
let motorcycles = map(data, Motorcycle)
// or
let motorcycles = map(data, Motorcycle.init)
```

Comment: Despite being pretty certain that this is not possible, since the class name gets parsed as a type, I'm still curious how we might do something like this, for the benefit of succinctness.

Comment: I've seen the same exact question a few days ago on a Slack :) Unluckily, for now there is no better way to do that than what yourself said already (a generator function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

"Knock knock."
"Who's there?"
"An input validator."
"An input validator who?"
`true`

---

Update: As of Swift 2.0, you can indeed pass init, eg. `String.init` or `Motorcycle.init`.